# Howto avoid the child-component is called twice when using one html for mobile and normal view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I'm having some trouble with my first Angular2 app (with Bootstrap). It is calling the component multiple times. I think because the childcomponent (

Parent html file:

```
 <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
<b>{{studievoortgangStudent?.StudentNaam}}</b>
<div *ngFor="let studievoortgang of studievoortgangStudent?.Studievoortgang">
    <b>{{studievoortgang.CROHONaam}}</b>
    <table class="table table-responsive" *ngFor="let fase of studievoortgang.Fasen">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>{{fase.NaamFase}}</th>
                <th></th>
                <th>{{fase.AantalTeBehalenEC}}</th>
                <th>{{fase.AantalVirtueelTotaalEC}}</th>
                <th>{{fase.AantalVastTeStellenEC}}</th>
                <th>{{fase.AantalWerkelijkTotaalEC}}</th>
            </tr>
            <tr [ngSwitch]="userinfo?.taalid=='2'">
                <th></th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">Result</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>Resultaat</th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">EC value</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>EC waarde</th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">EC virtual</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>EC virtueel</th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">EC to be determined</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>EC vast te stellen</th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">EC determined</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>EC vastgesteld</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let eindresultaat of fase.Eindresultaten; ">
            <tr data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{eindresultaat.OpmerkingEindresultaat}}" [ngStyle]="{'color':eindresultaat.KleurEindresultaat}">
                <td>
                    <button (click)="show[eindresultaat.Cursus] = !show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" title="Toon toetsen">
                        <span *ngIf="!show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                        <span *ngIf="show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                    </button>
                    {{eindresultaat.Cursus}}
                </td>
                <td>{{eindresultaat.Eindresultaat}}</td>
                <td>{{eindresultaat.CursusEC}}</td>
                <td>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVirtueelEC}}</td>
                <td>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC}}</td>
                <td>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="show[eindresultaat.Cursus]">
                <td colspan="6">
                    <studievoortgang-detail-component [toetsmatrijs]="eindresultaat.Toetsmatrijs">Loading...</studievoortgang-detail-component>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
 </div>
 <div class="hidden-md hidden-lg">
<b>{{studievoortgangStudent?.StudentNaam}}</b>
<div *ngFor="let studievoortgang of studievoortgangStudent?.Studievoortgang">
    <b>{{studievoortgang.CROHONaam}}</b>
    <table class="table table-responsive" *ngFor="let fase of studievoortgang.Fasen">
        <thead>
            <tr [ngSwitch]="userinfo?.taalid=='2'">
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">{{fase.NaamFase}}</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>{{fase.NaamFase}}</th>
                <th *ngSwitchCase="true">Result</th>
                <th *ngSwitchDefault>Resultaat</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody *ngFor="let eindresultaat of fase.Eindresultaten">
            <tr data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{eindresultaat.OpmerkingEindresultaat}}" [ngStyle]="{'color':eindresultaat.KleurEindresultaat}">
                <td>
                    <button (click)="show[eindresultaat.Cursus] = !show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" title="Toon toetsen">
                        <span *ngIf="!show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                        <span *ngIf="show[eindresultaat.Cursus]" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"></span>
                    </button>
                    {{eindresultaat.Cursus}}
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr *ngIf="show[eindresultaat.Cursus]">
                <td colspan="2">
                    <table class="table table-responsive">
                        <tr [ngSwitch]="userinfo?.taalid=='2'">
                            <td *ngSwitchCase="true">
                                <div><b>EC value: </b>{{eindresultaat.CursusEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC determined: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC virtual: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVirtueelEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC to be determined: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC}}</div>

                            </td>
                            <td *ngSwitchDefault>
                                <div><b>EC waarde: </b>{{eindresultaat.CursusEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC vastgesteld: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastgesteldeEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC virtueel: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVirtueelEC}}</div>
                                <div><b>EC vast te stellen: </b>{{eindresultaat.EindresultaatVastTeStellenEC}}</div>
                            </td>
                        <tr [ngSwitch]="userinfo?.taalid=='2'">
                            <th *ngSwitchCase="true">Tests</th>
                            <th *ngSwitchDefault>Toetsen</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <studievoortgang-detail-component [toetsmatrijs]="eindresultaat.Toetsmatrijs">Loading...</studievoortgang-detail-component>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

With this example the child-component is called twice and executes all services in that component twice. Any idea's on how to fix this, because i need a different layout for the mobile/tab and the desktop. (That's because one div = Hidden-xs Hidden-sm and the other one is hidden-md hidden-lg)

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that each of the components are in the dom and get the full treatment of lifecycle hooks from angular, just one of them is hidden based on bootstrap classes.

The way to fix it would be to add another `*ngIf` on each of the child components selectors, or add another condition to both instances of `*ngIf="show[eindresultaat.Cursus]` that would make sure that only one of them is active at any point in time.

Angular documentation on the differences between hiding and removing elements from the dom with `*ngIf` can be found here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngif